# Compile Package without installing needed libraries

Tags: compiling, make, configure

I try to compile `bluez-utils-3.36`, but after a try to **configure** the package, the error message: `configure: error: Bluetooth library is required`
 appeared.

The problem: i am **not allowed to update or install** anything on this machine, only compile. So i think the only way is to point at the libraries.
So i wrote `./configure -help` and found two Options:

```
  BLUEZ_CFLAGS    C compiler flags for BLUEZ, overriding pkg-config

  BLUEZ_LIBS      linker flags for BLUEZ, overriding pkg-config
```

So i added them to my command and complemented the path:

`./configure --prefix=/home/black/test/ltib/rootfs BLUEZ_CFLAGS=-I~/home/black/test/bluetooth/bluez-libs-3.36/include BLUEZ_LIBS="-L~/home/black/test/bluetooth/bluez-libs-3.36/src/.libs -lbluetooth"`

Now it worked with no errors.

But if i execute the command `make` then i get alot of errors, e.g.:

```
glib-helper.c:34:33: error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
glib-helper.c:35:30: error: bluetooth/rfcomm.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
glib-helper.c:36:29: error: bluetooth/l2cap.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
glib-helper.c:37:27: error: bluetooth/sco.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
glib-helper.c:38:27: error: bluetooth/sdp.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
glib-helper.c:39:31: error: bluetooth/sdp_lib.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

`Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden` is german and means: `folder or file not found`

How can i solve this?

Comment: [DISCLAIMER: I don't know whether bluez-libs-3.36 is compatible with bluez-5.33] Did you actually make and install  `bluez-libs-3.36`, or just unpack the archive? Although it appears to *contain* the bluetooth headers, they are not within an appropriate directory structure `<prefix>/include/bluetooth/`. You should be able to install it in your home directory by specifying `--prefix=$HOME` to the configure script. Then you can tell the bluez configure script to look in $HOME for bluetooth: either via the indicated variables or by setting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to include `$HOME/lib/pkgconfig/`

Comment: Im sorry, i made a mistake, i confused``bluez-5.33` with `bluez-utils-3.36` i changed it in the question. No i did not make or install. I am not allowed to install anything, thats the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a problem with the paths you are supplying to the `configure` command:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/black/test/ltib/rootfs \
BLUEZ_CFLAGS=-I~/home/black/test/bluetooth/bluez-libs-3.36/include \
BLUEZ_LIBS="-L~/home/black/test/bluetooth/bluez-libs-3.36/src/.libs -lbluetooth"
```

When the `~` character has not preceding whitespace, it doesn't expand to the path to your home directory.  Consider the output of:

```
$ echo  -I~/foo
-I~/foo
```

Versus:

```
$ echo  -I ~/foo
-I /home/lars/foo
```

You can simply replace `~` with `$HOME`.  Even with that fix, your paths look suspect:

```
~/home/black/test/bluetooth/bluez-libs-3.36/include
```

Assuming that your username is `black`, this would expand to:

```
/home/black/home/black/test/...
```

Which seems likely to be incorrect.

Try fixing the `-I` and `-L` paths and re-running configure.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did not knew this. I changed it like this: `-L~/test/bluetooth/...` but it still won't compile, same errors. I compiled the glib Package and got a file called `libglib-2.0.so`. Can i instruct the Makefile somehow to use it?

I have to tell the compiler somehow where to find these missing files. Any ideas?

Comment: I mean Linker, not compiler, sry.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myselve. Copy the folder "include" from `bluez-libs-3.36` and move the copy to `bluez-utils-3.36\common`. Then rename the copied folder from "include" to "bluetooth". Now it should compile without errors.

Comment: Thx to larsks for helping me with the path problem

Comment: `cd bluez-libs-3.36/common ; ln -s ../include bluetooth`